Selecting a random rectangle but weighted by area:
While doing some exercises from Leetcode, I faced one problem that requires selecting a random integer point internal from a set of non-overlapping rectangles (https://leetcode.com/problems/random-point-in-non-overlapping-rectangles/description/). While selecting a random integer point is somewhat trivial, the question requires the point selection to be equally likely from the entire area of all rectangles.
The solution I came with was to choose a rectangle randomly but weighted on the area and from it, randomly selected integer points from inside. In python, I have been using this code:
# select one rectangle randomly but weighting rectangles areas
selected = 0
total_area = self.rects_area[0]

for i in range(1, len(self.rects_area)):
    total_area += self.rects_area[i]
    selected = i if random() <= self.rects_area[i] / total_area else selected

with:
- rects: List[List[int]], with rects[i] = [ai, bi, xi, yi], (ai, bi) -> bottom left and (xi,yi) -> top right
- rects_area List[int]: area of each rects[i] using the same indexing

I'm passing in 31 of the 35 tests but the last 4 seems to take into account the distribution. So, my question is if the last line (selected = i if...) does indeed selected a rectangle randomly but weighted on the size. The insight I got came from a famous problem in which you have to randomly choose numbers from a stream in which you don't know how many will come. The first is 1/1, the second 1/2, the third 1/3 and so on so I adapted it to use the area as the numerator and the total area to that point as the denominator. So, for 3 triangles of areas: 2,3 and 5, the probabilities would be 2/2, 3/5 and 5/7.
Is my logic incorrect?

You did not show enough code, but i assume your area calculation is wrong ( because i cant find it in your post). The first comment on that leetcode page has a tip for that

This is just a portion of the code. In this question, I'm just trying to validate if the probability function is correct.

Yes, I found out that this is the correct approach. There are better solutions but the equation is correct.
